# Update the table data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table which fetch the data from database except the issued column. The number of row in that table is not fixed. There is an update button and which update the record. After entering the value in issued column i update that record.My data is not updating in the table . I have doubt how to give name to to the td element of the table.Code for table is

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
<table  >
 <thead>
  <tr >
  <th width="50px" >Sl.No.</th>
  <th style="display:none;" >Txn ID.</th>
 <th width="175px">Stationery Type</th>
 <th width="73px">REQUESTED</th>
 <th width="73px">ISSUED</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-row-2" >
                                           
   <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
   <td style="display:none;"><?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?></td>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationerytype);?></td>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->REQUESTED);?></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyissued" > </td>
    </TABLE>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn pull-right" style="margin-left:375px; margin-bottom:30px;">
</form>
```

Mysql code to update database is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {


$samplecount=$_GET["total"];
        for($i=0;$i<$samplecount;$i++){
            
$status="issued";   
$txnid=$_POST['txnid'];
$stationeryqtyissued=$_POST['stationeryqtyissued'];
$sql="update tblstationerystock set status=:status,stationeryqtyissued=:stationeryqtyissued where txnid=:txnid";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationeryqtyissued',$stationeryqtyissued[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':txnid',$txnid[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$_SESSION['msg']="Stationery Added successfully";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to you form

```
<input type="hidden" id="txnid" name="txnid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?>">
```

If you want to  send an array

```
<input type="hidden" name="txnid[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?>">
```

then you would have more than one row for that to work

and you can then

get it by

```
$txnid=$_POST['txnid'];
```

But that is no array, so that should be valid

```
$query->bindParam(':stationeryqtyissued',$stationeryqtyissued,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':txnid',$txnid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

So i am unclear why you are running a loop for the update over $total that i also don't see in your form.

```
 <td style="display:none;"><?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?></td>
```

Would not send data to your php  with POST or GET

Comment: Txnid is already there in the form.Table has more then one row and i want all row to update one by one single click.The $total is the value which defines the number of row in that table

Comment: td is no iput filed and you can add soe myn as you want also you can check the content  of $_POST and see what os init, and hen you check it  could be empty, as i said you code makes bnot much sense. i change my answer to show you how to agg an array to a hidden

Comment: can i put <input type="hidden" name="txnid[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?>"> inside the <td> element

Comment: Thanx iit is working i have put the remark and issued in also in array